# How to extract images from Word Document from Linux

Tags: linux, microsoft-word

Is there a (Linux) command-line tool to extract all the images from a MS Word document, (preferably one that could handle the .docx format)?

Comment: Is this a linux version with a UI or Command Line Only?

Comment: @Jeff - A command-line utility would be useful for large batch mode operations.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since docx files are zip files you can unzip the docx file and then pick out the image files.

I have no Microsoft Office to test so I downloaded some random docx files from the internet. It seems that the images are always stored in a `word/media` directory in the archive.

This command will extract all files from the `media` directory from the archive:

```
unzip foo.docx "word/media/*"
```

This command will extract only `*.jpeg` files:

```
unzip foo.docx "*.jpeg"
```

Note that you have to specify `"*.jpg"` if the files are saved as `jpg` instead of `jpeg`. I assume that it is also possible that images are stored using a different format. I have no idea whether images can be stored in another location other than the `word/media` directory. You can use `unzip -l` to list the contents of the archive.

Comment: Well thats useful! Do you know if this holds for the older .doc formats?

Comment: The older `doc` format was not zipped. It was either a monolithic XML or a binary blob. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word#File_formats).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an open source Python program called [ofc_media](https://github.com/johnhcc/ofc_mediax) that basically does the unzipping mentioned in lesmana's answer, but automates the search process a bit. It also works on OpenDocument format documents, can limit the extraction to certain file extensions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Saving a Word document as a web page is a technique used on Windows to extract all the images into a folder: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555171

It might be long winded, but perhaps you could control Open Office on Linux from the command line to extract the images, possibly by converting to a web page and ending up with the images in the supporting folder it would create.

Comment: I found this problematic. Some of my images became EMZ files - compressed EMF I believe. Noting on my Windows 10 system could open the EMZs (did not try it on my Linux box). However, renaming the *.docx to *.zip and opening it provided access to the EMF files which I could then readily use.